# When to stop importing new chain segments from Rinkeby testnet?

Tags: testnets, rinkeby, geth-clique

I am using geth to sync up with the Rinkeby testnet using the command: `geth --rinkeby --syncmode "fast"`. First it downloaded the blocks, then account states, and now new chain segments are being imported. Can I stop the processes now and continue with creating account and start developing? Or I would have to wait until a specific message gets printed on the screen?

Comment: I do not really understand. You cannot "stop" importing new hain segments, as new blocks are being created every x seconds. You can start working now, but you will keep getting new chain segments/blocks because that is the way it works

Comment: Hello Florian, I am getting messages like this: INFO [12-02|13:20:31.510] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1     txs=4   mgas=0.104  elapsed=10.224ms  mgasps=10.219   number=5542375 hash=6f2f45…4d847a dirty=34.99MiB. It means I am now online and can close this terminal and start working?

Comment: Use ganache or infura that is much easier for development

Comment: What does eth.syncing prints in geth's console? Is eth.blockNumber close to the latest block in etherscan? Since it prints "blocks=1" it appears to have finished syncing, a block is generated every 15 seconds so it is natural new chaing segments will have length=1.